# Background color over specific width of an editable textarea

Tags: html, css, gmail, background-color

First, what I am trying to do:
Gmail is wrapping plain text emails (RFC stuff I prefer not to comment) and I want to know where the wrap is going to occur.

So I plan to add some custom `CSS` rules to change the color of the background to light grey at the 78 characters limit and to switch to a monospace font.

The bad news is that I know nearly nothing about `HTML` or `CSS`, but I succeeded however in doing some basic stuff with Opera (and the outstanding DragonFly tool I have just discovered) by creating a `gmail.css` like this:

```
.editable {
   background: #DDDDDD !important;
   font-family:monospace !important;
}
```

and activating it with `Edit site preference...`. So 66% of the job is done (but 2% from a difficulty point of view).

Then, I searched how to setup this width but could not find any working solution. Usually, answers propose to create a new element, but that is not what I want to do: the textarea should be as wide as the window, and this is just the color behind which should give an indication of the limit.

Note also that I cannot edit anything else than the CSS (or I need to know how to do it!).

Here is a snippet taken with DragonFly of the elements I am trying to modify:

```
<table cellpadding="0" class="cf An" id=":il">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="Aq"> </td>
            <td class="Ap">ev
                <div id=":in" class="Ar As aoE" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="At">
                        <textarea id=":ik" class="Ak aXjCH" style="" aria-label="Compose reply" spellcheck="true" itacorner="6,7:1,1,0,0" tabindex="1" form="nosend"/>ev
                    </div>
                </div>    
                <div id=":im" class="Ar Au Ao" style="display: block;">
                    <div id=":ir" class="Am Al editable LW-avf" hidefocus="true" aria-label="Compose reply" g_editable="true" role="textbox" contenteditable="true" style="direction: ltr; min-height: 85px;" tabindex="1">ev
                        <br/>
                        This is the editable content!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="Aq"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So you want only the left part of the editable area to be grey? I think the simplest way is to create an image that is 1 pixel high and as wide as you need, and to use that for a background with `url('image') repeat-y`

Answer (score 0):

Because I am nice with me, I will answer my own question... The easiest solution I found is to use `linear-gradient`. I used below constant size, so if you try on your side, you might need to tune the size a little bit. Gmail is wrapping after the 76th character.

In addition, a little trick to make the new compose window bigger, though it is not related with the question.

```
/* Works for Opera Linux 12.15 and Gmail July 2013 */

/* Left side, non-wrapped, stays white, right side is light grey. */
.editable {
    /* Size is in px because the textarea can contains different fonts */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 612px, #eeeeee 1px)  !important;
    font-family:monospace !important;
}

/* Increase the size of new compose windows */
div[role=dialog] {
    float: right !important;
    width: 1000px !important;
}
```